# assign variable powerpoint.presentation

Tags: variables, vb6, powerpoint, presentation

I have a little problem, I use vb6 to modifications to a powerpoint through code. When I open it from vb6 assigned it to a global variable to handle it from a differents procedures . My question is how to assign the powerpoint to a variable if it was already open before starting my program.

I trying this code but not works

```
dim ppt as powerpoint.presentation
Set ppt = GetObject(pptfile) ' pptfile is powerpoint path and filename that is opened
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a string, check your string. There is no need to quote it. Your code works here.

If file is not open excel opens hidden without the file. When your reference goes out of scope excel closes.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim ppt As Excel.Workbook
    pptfile = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Super.xls"
    Set ppt = GetObject(pptfile)
    MsgBox ppt.application & " " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    MsgBox ppt.FullNameURLEncoded
End Sub
```